# Can LP with bounded feasible region be converted to LP with unbounded feasible region after adding artificial variables?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In Big-M method we add artificial variables to a linear programming problem(call it $p$) to convert it to a secondary problem(call it $p^\prime$) so we can find basic feasible solution to start Simplex algorithm.
Does there exist a linear programming problem with bounded feasible region which will have unbounded feasible region after adding artificial variables?

Comment: did I answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

This holds true for all feasible bounded problems. A constraint $a^Tx \geq b$ with $b > 0$ becomes $a^Tx-s_i+ a_i = b$ with $s_i$ the slack variable and $a_i$ the excess variable. If $(x,s,a)$ is feasible, then $(x,s+\alpha,a+\alpha)$ is also feasible for any $\alpha>0$, so the new feasible region is unbounded.

Based on the comment it seems like you are interested in whether the projection of the feasible region of $p'$ onto the variables in $p$ is unbounded. That can also be the case, but not necessarily. As a simple example, consider the set $S_1=\{x\in\mathbb{R} : 1 \leq x \leq 2\}$. After adding slacks and an artificial variable, this becomes the set $S_2=\{(x,a,s_1,s_2) \in\mathbb{R}^4 : x-s_1+a=1, x+s_2=2\}$. The constraint $x \geq 1$ can be violated arbitrarily by increasing the value of $a$ (for example, $(0,1,0,2) \in S_2$), so the projection of $S_2$ onto $x$ is $x \leq 2$.

Comment: Is there a simple LP example to provide intuition? I consider a right-angled triangle with its right-angled vertex positioned on $(1,1)$ on plane. If I add artificial variable how does that triangle become unbounded? (I consider all artificial variables positive-valued)

Comment: @FreeMind I may have misunderstood your question as the example did not discuss the original triangle but considered the higher dimensional space. I have added some clarification that deals with the triangle. It demonstrates that all inequalities with an artificial variable no longer need to hold, which may cause the feasible region to become unbounded.